# Where can I download mysql jdbc jar from?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jar

I installed and tried to use jasper report studio. The first brick wall you hit when you try to create a datasource for your reports is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The forums say I need to install a jar on the classpath. I have no idea how to do this, so the first hurdle is how to get the jar. The only place I can find is this:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

but this unfortunately gives you an msi installer, not a jar. I don't want to install stuff, just get the jar.

I have mysql DB installed, had have trawled through the install dir in program files, but can't find the jar.

Anyone know the official (not malware site) way to get hold of the mysql jar?  It seems bizarre that its so hard to find.

I have windows 8 64 bit and mysql 5.6.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Go to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j and with in the dropdown select "Platform Independent" then it will show you the options to download tar.gz file or zip file.

Download zip file and extract it, with in that you will find `mysql-connector-XXX.jar` file

If you are using maven then you can add the dependency from the link http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Select the version you want to use and add the dependency in your `pom.xml` file

Comment: If using W10, note the requirement to choose "PLATFORM INDEPENDENT" here. Otherwise you will end up downloading a useless MSI file which will install all sorts of crap, taking up space on your main hard drive (even though it claims, falsely, that you have the option to install elsewhere) and will NOT install any .jar file AT ALL. Typical Windoze crapware experience, designed on purpose to waste your time and cause annoyance.

Answer (score 6):

If you have WL server installed, pick it up from under
\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\mysql-connector-java-commercial-5.1.17-bin.jar

Otherwise, download it from:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar.zip

Comment: I found another way, download the MSI, but dont install it (if you do it does nothing - it doesnt give you the jar).  Instead install 7zip, then use 7-zip to extract the mysql jdbc jar from the MSI. Then copy it to somewhere on your HD.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know it was possible to unzip .MSI. Thanks.

Comment: it does give us the jar. default location - C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\

Comment: @Roshith. Yes. www.java2s.com is a great reference for many Java related things

Comment: Why download from third party site instead of oracle/mysql?

Comment: Yes Installers are often zip files and it is something to try in last resort but as soon as you are provided with a ZIP or direct download why going through the hassle?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner using Maven:

```
mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38
```

Then, with default settings, it's available in:

```
$HOME/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
```

Just replace the version number if you need a different one.