# Datahub extension for Hybris 6.2.0.10

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

i'm unable to find the jar file to connect mysqldb with Hybris. I don't have access a SUser id or access to Wiki. Assuming its a very small file, can anyone please send me the path or email me the file (sagarmeena416@gmail.com)?

datahub-extention-archetype-6.2.0.10-RC4.jar file

I am looking for "datahub-extention-archetype-6.2.0.10-RC4.jar" file not MySQL connector jar. Please help, I have read the links users had posted and its not the same

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should already be in Hybris (hybris\bin\platform\lib\dbdriver\)

Comment: This file is not in this location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I download mysql jdbc jar from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546417/where-can-i-download-mysql-jdbc-jar-from)

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546417/where-can-i-download-mysql-jdbc-jar-from   .You can find the steps for downloading the jar there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author asked other users to send him a jar file by email.

Comment: I am looking for "datahub-extention-archetype-6.2.0.10-RC4.jar" file not MySQL connector jar. Please help, I have read the links you had posted and its not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this file (with a different version) under "hybris/bin/ext-integration/datahub/solution-book" in DataHub 1808. But, I have not seen a DataHub installer for 6.2 in SAP SWDC.

You can try to create Incident ticket on SAP: https://support.sap.com/en/my-support/product-support.html
Maybe they can help you.

Comment: its not in the location you mentioned...thanks for replying though