# Keep getting a java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver, error but my connector is in the right folder

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, command-line

Trying to connect sql database and java code but getting the no driver found error. I've downloaded the connector into the corresponding folder but can't find what's wrong

i tried running:
java -cp .;C:\asd\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar JdbcSelectTest

through the command line but it gave me the error

```
import java.sql.*;  // Using 'Connection', 'Statement' and 'ResultSet' classes in java.sql package

public class JdbcSelectTest {   // Save as "JdbcSelectTest.java"
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try (
         // Step 1: Allocate a database 'Connection' object
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
               "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC",
               "myuser", "xxxx");   // For MySQL only
               // The format is: "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databaseName", "username", "password"

         // Step 2: Allocate a 'Statement' object in the Connection
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ) {
         // Step 3: Execute a SQL SELECT query. The query result is returned in a 'ResultSet' object.
         String strSelect = "select title, price, qty from books";
         System.out.println("The SQL statement is: " + strSelect + "\n"); // Echo For debugging

         ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);

         // Step 4: Process the ResultSet by scrolling the cursor forward via next().
         //  For each row, retrieve the contents of the cells with getXxx(columnName).
         System.out.println("The records selected are:");
         int rowCount = 0;
         while(rset.next()) {   // Move the cursor to the next row, return false if no more row
            String title = rset.getString("title");
            double price = rset.getDouble("price");
            int    qty   = rset.getInt("qty");
            System.out.println(title + ", " + price + ", " + qty);
            ++rowCount;
         }
         System.out.println("Total number of records = " + rowCount);

      } catch(SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }  // Step 5: Close conn and stmt - Done automatically by try-with-resources (JDK 7)
```

I was expecting the database to connect, any help is appreciated! I believe the error has something to do with the input on line 8

Comment: Can you try with quote in lib path: java -cp ".;C:\asd\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar" JdbcSelectTest

Comment: It says that it was an unrecognized option

Comment: Are you sure the file `C:\asd\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar` exists?

Answer (score -2):

You have to include the Driver jar in your library. I am using this "mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar".

Ref. [Where can I download mysql jdbc jar from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546417/where-can-i-download-mysql-jdbc-jar-from)

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/

Put the file to your classpath.

Comment: You really shouldn't do that. Libraries (jar files) have a clear purpose and you really don't need to compile things yourself nor add everything to your own jar.

Comment: And that is relevant how? If you use the commandline, you can add multiple libraries to the classpath using `-cp`.

Comment: He is getting no driver found error so I asked him to include all required jars in one directory. Ref. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html

Comment: No, you are suggesting he includes the **sources** of MySQL Connector/J in his project and that is **not** the right approach.

Comment: Okay I made a mistake. Should be just the driver class jar.

Comment: The `bin` directory has nothing to do with it.The JAR file has to be on the `CLASSPATH`. Clearly it isn't, despite the OP's belief.

Comment: Okay I am not an expert so I think people should listen to you. And my bin actually means classpath but anyways here I just arbitrarily assign a directory for classpath as you see java files are in bin folder. This is misleading so I will edit my answer now.