# Not Able to Connect JDBC-Hikari To my Micronaut App

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp, micronaut, sql2o

Error I am Getting after running `sudo ./gradlew run` :

> Task :run FAILED
>   12:03:13.440 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69
>   12:03:13.445 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [javax.sql.DataSource] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

How my Application.yml looks like :

---

```
micronaut:
  application:
    name: freshdb2
```

---

```
#datasources.default: {}

datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: root
    password: ""
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing driver, you should add dependency `mysql-connector-java`, for gradle add:

```
runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13'
```

Comment: I Didnt Got you!
Can you Please Copy paste the Correction ?

Comment: @ukdev remove `driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Now I am Getting this Error
> Task :run FAILED
12:49:02.762 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@3d4eac69
12:49:02.769 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [javax.sql.DataSource] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Comment: @ukdev you are probably missing mysql jar in classpath see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546417/where-can-i-download-mysql-jdbc-jar-from

Comment: Man, I checked Everything It is Still not working and giving this Error message:
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

Message: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
Path Taken: DataSource.dataSource([DatasourceConfiguration datasourceConfiguration])

Comment: @ukdev you should have `mysql-connector-java`, e.g. in gradle `runtime group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13'`

Comment: Thank you So much It worked For me.  http://makble.com/gradle-example-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-in-eclipse

Comment: @ukdev Great, you can accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Done. Thanks Again.

Comment: As of MySQL 8.0 [the JDBC driver class name has changed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`. The old class name has been deprecated (but is still present in MySQL Connector/J at least through version 8.0.28).

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the message:

> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [javax.sql.DataSource]

I'm not using MySQL, just trying to unpick how to use JPA from [Micronaut Data Guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html) and others using H2.

It turns out I had incorrectly copied the datasource properties into `application.yml`.  The above message is all you get to tell you this.

In my case the back quotes in the following had become something else.

```
datasources:   
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`}
    username: ${JDBC_USER:sa}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:""}
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:org.h2.Driver}
    dialect: ${JDBC_DIALECT:H2}
```