# Can not connect to sql database through java

Tags: java

I have practically no experience with sql besides just learning about it yesterday in my java OOP class and trying to figure it out through YouTube. I am trying to use this free sql database website and be able to control it through java.  Any tips on what I am doing wrong?

`

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
            
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql9.freesqldatabase.com:3306/sql9581604","sql9581604","ih8h2nhpxC");

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

`

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)   
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Tried watching tutorials on YouTube but just keep getting all different errors.

Comment: The driver class for Mysql does not appear to be in your classpath.  There should be documentation on the free-db website your are using for what JAR to download.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548704/13963086

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the `jar` file containing the jdbc connector in the same path of the code file.